# Cannot use dput for data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have following data.table for which I cannot use output of dput command to recreate it:

```
> ddt
   Unit Anything index new
1:    A      3.4     1   1
2:    A      6.9     2   1
3:   A1      1.1     1   2
4:   A1      2.2     2   2
5:    B      2.0     1   3
6:    B      3.0     2   3
> 
> 
> str(ddt)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  6 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Unit    : Factor w/ 3 levels "A","A1","B": 1 1 2 2 3 3
 $ Anything: num  3.4 6.9 1.1 2.2 2 3
 $ index   : num  1 2 1 2 1 2
 $ new     : int  1 1 2 2 3 3
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
 - attr(*, "sorted")= chr  "Unit" "Anything"
> 
> 
> dput(ddt)
structure(list(Unit = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"A1", "B"), class = "factor"), Anything = c(3.4, 6.9, 1.1, 2.2, 
2, 3), index = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), new = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L)), .Names = c("Unit", "Anything", "index", "new"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x8948f68>, sorted = c("Unit", 
"Anything"))
>
```

On pasting I get following error:

```
> dt = structure(list(Unit = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
+ "A1", "B"), class = "factor"), Anything = c(3.4, 6.9, 1.1, 2.2, 
+ 2, 3), index = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), new = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
+ 3L)), .Names = c("Unit", "Anything", "index", "new"), row.names = c(NA, 
+ -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x8948f68>, sorted = c("Unit", 
Error: unexpected '<' in:
"3L)), .Names = c("Unit", "Anything", "index", "new"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <"
> "Anything"))
Error: unexpected ')' in ""Anything")"
```

Where is the problem and how can it be corrected? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that `dput` prints out external pointer address (this is something that `data.table` uses internally, and will reconstruct when required), which you can't really use.

If you manually cut out the `.internal.selfref` part, it will work just fine, except for a one-time complaint from `data.table` for some operations.

You could add an FR to `data.table` about this, but it will require modifying the base function from `data.table`, similar to how `rbind` is currently handled.

Comment: I had the same issues and all I did was convert my factor columns to character and it worked fine.

Answer (score 6):

I have also found this behavior rather annoying. So I have created my own `dput` function that ignores the `.internal.selfref` attribute.

```
dput <- function (x, file = "", control = c("keepNA", "keepInteger", 
                                    "showAttributes")) 
{
  if (is.character(file)) 
    if (nzchar(file)) {
      file <- file(file, "wt")
      on.exit(close(file))
    }
  else file <- stdout()
  opts <- .deparseOpts(control)
  # adding these three lines for data.tables
  if (is.data.table(x)) {
    setattr(x, '.internal.selfref', NULL)
  }
  if (isS4(x)) {
    clx <- class(x)
    cat("new(\"", clx, "\"\n", file = file, sep = "")
    for (n in .slotNames(clx)) {
      cat("    ,", n, "= ", file = file)
      dput(slot(x, n), file = file, control = control)
    }
    cat(")\n", file = file)
    invisible()
  }
  else .Internal(dput(x, file, opts))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you sure it will not affect dput's output for all other objects? One can always rename this function to dputdt to be used for data.table objects only.

Comment: why so complicated? doesn't simply `dput = function(x, ...) { if(is.data.table(x)) { setattr(x, '.internal.selfref', NULL) }; base::dput(x, ...) }` work? or perhaps better yet, replace `is.data.table` with `inherits`

Answer (score 1):

If you've already `dput` the file and you don't feel much like manually editing before `dget`, you can use the following

```
data.table.parse<-function (file = "", n = NULL, text = NULL, prompt = "?", keep.source = getOption("keep.source"), 
                            srcfile = NULL, encoding = "unknown") 
{
  keep.source <- isTRUE(keep.source)
  if (!is.null(text)) {
    if (length(text) == 0L) 
      return(expression())
    if (missing(srcfile)) {
      srcfile <- "<text>"
      if (keep.source) 
        srcfile <- srcfilecopy(srcfile, text)
    }
    file <- stdin()
  }
  else {
    if (is.character(file)) {
      if (file == "") {
        file <- stdin()
        if (missing(srcfile)) 
          srcfile <- "<stdin>"
      }
      else {
        filename <- file
        file <- file(filename, "r")
        if (missing(srcfile)) 
          srcfile <- filename
        if (keep.source) {
          text <- readLines(file, warn = FALSE)
          if (!length(text)) 
            text <- ""
          close(file)
          file <- stdin()
          srcfile <- srcfilecopy(filename, text, file.mtime(filename), 
                                 isFile = TRUE)
        }
        else {
          text <- readLines(file, warn = FALSE)
          if (!length(text)) {
            text <- ""
          } else {
            text <- gsub("(, .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x[0-9A-Fa-f]+>)","",text,perl=TRUE)
          }
          on.exit(close(file))
        }
      }
    }
  }
  #  text <- gsub("(, .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x[0-9A-F]+>)","",text)
  .Internal(parse(file, n, text, prompt, srcfile, encoding))
}
data.table.get <- function(file, keep.source = FALSE)
  eval(data.table.parse(file = file, keep.source = keep.source))
dtget <- data.table.get
```

then change your calls of `dget` to `dtget`. Note that due to the inline parsing, this will make `dtget` slower than `dget`, so use it only in circumstances where you could be retrieving an object of type `data.table`.