# Keep action before and after for more than one unique values

Tags: r

First data frame with values:

```r
testa <- structure(list(creation_date = structure(c(14092, 14092, 14095, 14095,
 14095, 14095, 14095, 14097, 14097, 14097, 14098, 14098, 14099, 14099, 14102, 
14112, 14113, 14113, 14113, 14114, 14114, 14116, 14116, 14116, 14116, 14116, 
14117, 14118, 14118, 14120, 14120, 14120, 14127, 14127, 14127, 14127, 14130, 
14131, 14131, 14131, 14133, 14136, 14137, 14137, 14137, 14138, 14139, 14145, 
14145, 14145, 14147, 14147, 14151, 14155, 14157, 14164, 14166, 14176, 14176, 
14180, 14181, 14181, 14183, 14183, 14185, 14192, 14193, 14197, 14202, 14202, 
14210, 14211, 14216, 14216, 14216, 14216, 14229, 14236, 14250, 14265, 14266, 
14273, 14276, 14288, 14289, 14294, 14297, 14299, 14299, 14300, 14301, 14301, 
14305, 14308, 14309, 14310, 14310, 14311, 14313, 14319, 14326, 14326, 14327, 
14327, 14333, 14334, 14335, 14373, 14380, 14384, 14384, 14391, 14392, 14394, 
14403, 14406, 14407, 14428, 14433, 14438, 14438, 14438, 14438, 14441, 14441, 
14445, 14447, 14447, 14448, 14450, 14451, 14452, 14453, 14454, 14454, 14457, 
14468, 14468, 14470, 14480, 14484, 14485, 14485, 14491, 14495, 14496, 14499, 
14503, 14508, 14510, 14511, 14563, 14564, 14564, 14568, 14570, 14574, 14577, 
14581, 14581, 14581, 14583, 14584, 14584, 14588, 14590, 14591, 14592, 14592, 
14592, 14595, 14596, 14601, 14606, 14610, 14624, 14624, 14628, 14628, 14629, 
14629, 14633, 14633, 14642, 14644, 14645, 14647, 14651, 14651, 14652, 14663, 
14663, 14663, 14667, 14671, 14675, 14679, 14680, 14689, 14690, 14691, 14696, 
14711, 14734, 14740, 14749, 14757, 14758, 14769, 14777, 14777, 14779, 14779, 
14779, 14779, 14779, 14780, 14789, 14792, 14794, 14796, 14796, 14797, 14798, 
14798, 14802, 14804, 14816, 14816, 14817, 14817, 14818, 14818, 14821, 14825, 
14839, 14839, 14839, 14839, 14844, 14846, 14846, 14850, 14853, 14855, 14862, 
14864, 14865, 14875, 14894, 14894, 14895, 14895, 14896, 14904, 14911, 14911, 
14918, 14921, 14923, 14925, 14926, 14929, 14929, 14929, 14930, 14930, 14934, 
14937, 14939, 14943, 14946, 14953, 14953, 14953, 14955, 14956, 14958, 14958, 
14959, 14959, 14959, 14960, 14960, 14960, 14960, 14963, 14963, 14964, 14970, 
14977, 14978, 14978, 14979, 14979, 14981, 14981, 14981, 14985, 14988, 14988, 
14988, 14988, 14989, 14990, 14993, 14995, 14995, 14996, 14997, 15001, 15001, 
15001, 15001, 15002, 15003, 15004, 15004, 15004, 15004, 15005, 15006, 15008, 
15008, 15008, 15009, 15009, 15009, 15010, 15011, 15011, 15012, 15012, 15013, 
15013, 15013, 15015, 15015, 15016, 15018, 15018, 15019, 15021, 15022, 15022, 
15023, 15024, 15025, 15025, 15026, 15027, 15030, 15040, 15040, 15040, 15041, 
15041, 15041, 15042, 15043, 15044, 15044, 15048, 15049, 15049, 15049, 15049, 
15049, 15049, 15049, 15049, 15053, 15053, 15055, 15056, 15058, 15060, 15061, 
15062, 15064, 15064, 15065, 15065, 15068, 15068, 15069, 15069, 15069, 15070, 
15070, 15070, 15071, 15071, 15082, 15083, 15089, 15091, 15091, 15096, 15097, 
15097, 15099, 15099, 15100, 15101, 15101, 15101, 15102, 15102, 15103, 15105, 
15107, 15108, 15116, 15119, 15120, 15120, 15120, 15120, 15121, 15121, 15121, 
15122, 15122, 15126, 15131, 15131, 15131, 15132, 15133, 15133, 15134, 15136, 
15136, 15136, 15137, 15137, 15138, 15138, 15139, 15140, 15141, 15143, 15145, 
15145, 15147, 15147, 15148, 15149, 15149, 15153, 15159, 15167, 15169, 15170, 
15171, 15177, 15180, 15180, 15181, 15182, 15182, 15183, 15183, 15187, 15190, 
15191, 15191, 15194, 15197, 15199, 15200, 15202, 15202, 15202, 15209, 15209, 
15216, 15217, 15232, 15267, 15267, 15273, 15274, 15276, 15278, 15285, 15286, 
15294, 15295, 15296, 15297, 15299, 15301, 15306, 15308, 15313, 15315, 15315, 
15320, 15321, 15321, 15323, 15336, 15337, 15342, 15343, 15350, 15353, 15354, 
15362, 15367, 15374, 15378, 15378, 15389, 15392, 15393, 15406, 15407, 15432, 
15433, 15434, 15435, 15439, 15439, 15446, 15484, 15498, 15521, 15523, 15586, 
15586, 15590, 15594, 15596, 15597, 15716, 15889, 15894, 15939, 15986, 16034, 
16080, 16083, 16097, 16097, 16100, 16100, 16104, 16104, 16105, 16105, 16106, 
16108, 16109, 16113, 16150, 16182, 16182, 16193, 16194, 16195, 16196, 16200, 
16232, 16388, 16437, 16497, 16516, 16517, 16520, 16527, 16545, 16587, 16587, 
16603, 16617, 16617, 16618, 16618, 16620, 16621, 16622, 16623, 16623, 16630, 
16642, 16688), class = "Date"), r_id = c(84L, 113L, 838L, 1185L, 1414L, 1435L, 
1468L, 3409L, 3422L, 3425L, 4439L, 4910L, 5474L, 5684L, 7777L, 19784L, 22221L, 
22448L, 22613L, 24000L, 24452L, 26411L, 26427L, 26483L, 26807L, 26819L, 27856L, 
29092L, 30372L, 34807L, 35134L, 35251L, 44990L, 44993L, 45008L, 45189L, 50139L, 
50963L, 51778L, 52394L, 55378L, 60999L, 62587L, 62774L, 65476L, 73428L, 78207L, 
118857L, 119002L, 119084L, 131533L, 131560L, 149601L, 167442L, 171418L, 
195023L, 200138L, 234689L, 234720L, 244353L, 245291L, 247067L, 253718L, 
254218L, 257123L, 275462L, 276801L, 289332L, 300482L, 302044L, 324532L, 
325072L, 335725L, 336076L, 336188L, 338018L, 371478L, 389781L, 416550L, 
465822L, 469129L, 492481L, 500108L, 546427L, 548602L, 563246L, 575848L, 
583172L, 583219L, 584827L, 589187L, 591456L, 601077L, 614802L, 619492L, 
620710L, 620749L, 624092L, 630450L, 650846L, 674223L, 675073L, 675656L, 
677745L, 698048L, 702390L, 703514L, 841985L, 871733L, 886531L, 887162L, 
916929L, 918813L, 929247L, 965833L, 981665L, 984400L, 1080017L, 1096357L, 
1117133L, 1120273L, 1120569L, 1121944L, 1138807L, 1138973L, 1153928L, 1162517L, 
1162544L, 1168877L, 1181466L, 1183462L, 1188565L, 1191646L, 1197546L, 1197629L, 
1215656L, 1263154L, 1263753L, 1276124L, 1323970L, 1345520L, 1350188L, 1350294L, 
1381143L, 1395941L, 1397241L, 1415736L, 1433918L, 1452984L, 1467884L, 1472447L, 
1738857L, 1739990L, 1743148L, 1768575L, 1776956L, 1801241L, 1816389L, 1837464L, 
1837484L, 1837507L, 1853444L, 1854213L, 1854579L, 1878245L, 1892827L, 1895479L, 
1898131L, 1898816L, 1899486L, 1922627L, 1925875L, 1954380L, 1967839L, 1989724L, 
2069954L, 2070165L, 2090703L, 2091217L, 2099428L, 2099475L, 2125490L, 2126412L, 
2185880L, 2202416L, 2206113L, 2215345L, 2242412L, 2242446L, 2248711L, 2314801L, 
2320251L, 2320341L, 2345941L, 2369209L, 2395314L, 2421879L, 2430952L, 2488066L, 
2489965L, 2498122L, 2534210L, 2619341L, 2774617L, 2812656L, 2874597L, 2925439L, 
2933728L, 3009203L, 3058926L, 3059886L, 3074244L, 3074303L, 3074315L, 3074335L, 
3074615L, 3078080L, 3136580L, 3168962L, 3175780L, 3182473L, 3183780L, 3197285L, 
3199128L, 3199167L, 3225847L, 3249446L, 3337456L, 3338431L, 3340212L, 3341049L, 
3352914L, 3353351L, 3379573L, 3408179L, 3508189L, 3508263L, 3508573L, 3514053L, 
3549444L, 3562022L, 3563208L, 3593880L, 3614638L, 3632466L, 3681454L, 3693375L, 
3700488L, 3778750L, 3911733L, 3912439L, 3921014L, 3927649L, 3928224L, 3992839L, 
4048734L, 4049074L, 4106456L, 4120985L, 4140845L, 4163933L, 4173122L, 4190776L, 
4195481L, 4197547L, 4200460L, 4205672L, 4240382L, 4267223L, 4286288L, 4315980L, 
4350116L, 4405411L, 4409454L, 4413567L, 4420332L, 4425273L, 4445169L, 4446450L, 
4456327L, 4456371L, 4464836L, 4466918L, 4467092L, 4467118L, 4472199L, 4490173L, 
4491228L, 4495388L, 4536350L, 4581443L, 4589602L, 4590790L, 4599742L, 4600949L, 
4626615L, 4626696L, 4627210L, 4652757L, 4693779L, 4694139L, 4696303L, 4696338L, 
4696760L, 4707427L, 4736369L, 4755118L, 4761887L, 4766518L, 4775944L, 4810660L, 
4812559L, 4814463L, 4818619L, 4832046L, 4838495L, 4841394L, 4841409L, 4844339L, 
4844400L, 4847000L, 4856754L, 4882519L, 4889561L, 4890976L, 4900406L, 4901832L, 
4902363L, 4909203L, 4914293L, 4915870L, 4922443L, 4925614L, 4929630L, 4934525L, 
4934999L, 4960273L, 4962464L, 4966465L, 4982980L, 4986474L, 4993324L, 5017142L, 
5025184L, 5033040L, 5038422L, 5048056L, 5055328L, 5060288L, 5060733L, 5072582L, 
5121356L, 5221451L, 5221654L, 5223948L, 5228699L, 5238774L, 5238808L, 5239285L, 
5253953L, 5269258L, 5277215L, 5317237L, 5318641L, 5320815L, 5321294L, 5321775L, 
5321830L, 5329130L, 5332206L, 5332290L, 5371226L, 5371243L, 5398228L, 5398854L, 
5432879L, 5446014L, 5455108L, 5474857L, 5493538L, 5503156L, 5507828L, 5509004L, 
5540655L, 5544240L, 5546056L, 5555883L, 5557047L, 5560760L, 5561856L, 5570082L, 
5574767L, 5576523L, 5696528L, 5710975L, 5775037L, 5805088L, 5809437L, 5860014L, 
5863106L, 5864688L, 5900244L, 5901972L, 5905219L, 5918751L, 5919436L, 5923134L, 
5925213L, 5925665L, 5932815L, 5965720L, 5984702L, 6003801L, 6089124L, 6118493L, 
6131370L, 6133042L, 6140646L, 6140747L, 6147677L, 6152966L, 6153098L, 6157890L, 
6163213L, 6195437L, 6247196L, 6252607L, 6255580L, 6270002L, 6271914L, 6284555L, 
6298006L, 6312458L, 6313376L, 6318177L, 6323306L, 6323528L, 6326308L, 6331678L, 
6347270L, 6353306L, 6377737L, 6392068L, 6413905L, 6415159L, 6435150L, 6435898L, 
6449403L, 6462230L, 6462358L, 6501648L, 6575370L, 6657334L, 6686154L, 6700375L, 
6715669L, 6784341L, 6810120L, 6820140L, 6835059L, 6838346L, 6848707L, 6855446L, 
6862351L, 6900422L, 6944039L, 6950997L, 6959746L, 6988469L, 7031522L, 7052836L, 
7057609L, 7073977L, 7080464L, 7080829L, 7157631L, 7164321L, 7244226L, 7261166L, 
7430821L, 7828193L, 7840907L, 7905299L, 7918285L, 7934925L, 7955108L, 8032289L, 
8044811L, 8144756L, 8162684L, 8175536L, 8192011L, 8206533L, 8246284L, 8297524L, 
8320445L, 8388577L, 8420920L, 8421278L, 8478042L, 8482471L, 8493849L, 8513697L, 
8650004L, 8661914L, 8706782L, 8734466L, 8825974L, 8860673L, 8867460L, 8966737L, 
9042559L, 9138179L, 9199206L, 9201742L, 9352175L, 9387723L, 9417958L, 9604798L, 
9625357L, 9976528L, 9984037L, 10004648L, 10020192L, 10074535L, 10074578L, 
10166837L, 10729583L, 10924614L, 11277201L, 11298925L, 12241045L, 12241214L, 
12308951L, 12362685L, 12412314L, 12431700L, 14273438L, 17451028L, 17519227L, 
18370719L, 19250313L, 20197260L, 21034503L, 21100786L, 21376224L, 21376603L, 
21447453L, 21449198L, 21518178L, 21518251L, 21544470L, 21560145L, 21569134L, 
21620576L, 21650361L, 21720907L, 22570170L, 23208699L, 23222151L, 23438659L, 
23457703L, 23462570L, 23503733L, 23584894L, 24166442L, 26923151L, 27735925L, 
28833186L, 29198606L, 29200656L, 29271008L, 29408635L, 29748471L, 30563019L, 
30578534L, 30894890L, 31150765L, 31150888L, 31188760L, 31189111L, 31224046L, 
31232174L, 31236675L, 31256016L, 31273090L, 31412744L, 31641311L, 32489150L), 
participant_id = c(24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 
24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L )), row.names = c(NA, -589L), class = 
c("data.table", "data.frame" ), 
.internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000002c1ef0>)
```

Here the second dataframe with participant_id connected with testa dataframe:

```
testb <- structure(list(participant_id = c(24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L, 24534556L), awarded = structure(c(14137, 14151, 14160, 14326, 14371, 14459, 14475, 14480, 14539, 14573, 14576, 14621, 14629, 14633, 14637, 14644, 14676, 14723, 14797, 14839, 14851, 14883, 14887, 14901, 14915, 14924, 14925, 14928, 14972, 14977, 14981, 15004, 15005, 15006, 15018, 15020, 15033, 15042, 15059, 15062, 15065, 15084, 15100, 15108, 15109, 15119, 15126, 15129, 15161, 15169, 15172, 15207, 15231, 15232, 15268, 15290, 15309, 15327, 15330, 15362, 15388, 15420, 15422, 15435, 15439, 15446, 15456, 15477, 15493, 15495, 15497, 15500, 15523, 15535, 15562, 15565, 15602, 15614, 15621, 15662, 15664, 15671, 15672, 15685, 15694, 15733, 15736, 15738, 15755, 15797, 15801, 15806, 15848, 15854, 15869, 15881, 15903, 15915, 15957, 15966, 15968, 15973, 15977, 15996, 16000, 16010, 16016, 16080, 16085, 16096, 16098, 16149, 16165, 16175, 16184, 16188, 16199, 16205, 16218, 16240, 16265, 16294, 16350, 16363, 16461, 16516, 16562, 16565, 16660, 16698, 16835, 16855, 16860, 16868, 16911, 16919, 16955, 16975, 17004, 17028, 17098, 17128, 17134, 17140, 17191, 17199, 17214, 17337, 17352, 17358, 17387, 17476, 17526, 17564, 17567, 17577, 17689, 17726, 17889, 17900, 17914, 18035), class = "Date"), action_name = c("Nasw", "Dasw", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Eman", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Eit", "Nasw", "Dasw", "Ivin", "Nasw", "Dasw", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Ivin", "Eman", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Eit", "Dasw", "Dasw", "Dasw", "Nasw", "ru", "Dasw", "Ivin", "Eman", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Eit", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Nasw", "ru", "Nasw", "Dasw", "Eit", "Nasw", "Dasw", "Dasw", "Dasw", "Nasw", "Dasw", "Eman", "Nasw", "ru", "Dasw", "Dasw", "Nasw", "ru", "Nasw", "Dasw", "ru", "ru", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Dasw", "Nasw", "Dasw", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Dasw", "Nasw", "Nasw", "ru", "ru", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Dasw", "ru", "Nasw", "ru", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Dasw", "Dasw", "Dasw", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Dasw", "Nasw", "Dasw", "Dasw", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Gnd", "Nasw", "Dasw", "Dasw", "ru", "Nasw", "Dasw", "Nasw", "ru", "Dasw", "Gnd", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Eman", "Dasw", "Dasw", "Gnd", "Nasw", "ru", "Dasw", "ru", "Dasw", "Nasw", "Gnd", "Nasw", "ru", "Nasw", "Nasw", "ru", "Dasw", "Nasw", "Dasw", "Nasw", "Gnd", "Nasw", "ru", "Nasw", "Nasw", "ru", "Nasw", "Dasw", "Gnd", "Nasw", "ru", "Dasw", "Nasw", "Dasw", "Dasw", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Nasw", "Nasw", "ru", "Dasw", "Dasw", "Dasw", "Nasw" )), row.names = c(NA, -162L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame" ), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000002c1ef0>)
```

Using this it is possible to keep for the action_name of testb the first action before and after 2 days

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
library(janitor)
library(zoo)

testb_first= testb[,head(.SD,1), by = .(participant_id)] %>% 
  mutate(date_pre = awarded - 2,
         date_post = awarded + 2)

testb= testb[,head(.SD,1), by = .(participant,awarded)]

req_rows = testa %>%
  merge(award_first %>%
        by = "participant_id") %>%
  filter(creation_date >= date_pre,
         creation_date <= date_post,
         creation_date != awarded) %>%
  mutate(period = ifelse(creation_date<awarded, '2-day-pre', '2-day-pst'))
```

This command lines keep only the first day of the first action_name. How is it possible to keep for every unique action_name the first creation date and keep in testa for each one the 2-day-pre and 2-day-pst?

Comment: Don't share all of your data. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @M-- thank you. They are not all. It is only for one participant_id the example data. In the real dataset I have more than one id

Comment: In any case, you have `pointer_id` which is not supposed to be in your `dput`. If I copy/paste your data, I'll get an error and cannot reproduce your example. Cheers.

Comment: @M-- what do you mean pointer id?

Comment: @M-- it is the dput from R

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533332/cannot-use-dput-for-data-table-in-r

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200021/discussion-between-m-and-nathalie).