# R pROC coords() give suboptimal tresholds for my ROC curve

Tags: r, roc, proc-r-package

I have a bunch of predictors that could be useful for a diagnosis. Since I have more than 30 predictors, I selected only the predictors that are more useful in this diagnosis, using the AUC measure (area under the ROC curve).

```
library(pROC)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

#Sorted my variables by AUC in table.AUC (one col with AUCs, one col with variable names)

# Then extracted a list of all variables with an AUC>=0.7
list.predictors=table.auc %>% filter(AUC>=0.7) %>% dplyr::select(Variable) %>% unlist()

# Then did a purrr::map() to calculate the bests thresholds, senibility, specificity and positive and negative predictive values
map(list.predictors, .f=~{ 
  threshold=coords(roc(data$Illness,data[[.x]], levels=c("Healthy","Sick")), "best", ret = "threshold") %>% unlist()
  c2=data
  c2$NM=ifelse(data[[.x]]>=threshold,"1","0")
  TP=c2 %>% filter(NM!="0" & Illness=="Sick") %>% nrow()
  TN= c2 %>% filter(NM=="0" & Illness=="Healthy") %>% nrow()
  FP=c2 %>% filter(NM!="0" & Illness=="Healthy") %>% nrow()
  FN= c2 %>% filter(NM=="0" & Illness=="Sick") %>% nrow()
  tribble(~"name",~"threshold",~"Sen",~"Spe",~"PPV",~"PNV",
          .x,threshold, TP/(TP+FN), TN/(TN+FP), TP/(TP+FP), TN/(TN+FN)
  ) %>%
    mutate(across((Sen:PNV),~round(.x,2)),
           threshold=round(threshold,3)) %>% return() 
}) %>% bind_rows()
```

However, I have some weird sensibility and specificity for one predictor : Sen = 18%, Spe = 41%. Looking at the ROC curve, I think my function has failed to find the best threshold (and found one that doesn't even exist ??) .

[image: Sen and spe]

Looking at the [coords() documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/pROC/man/coords.html), it seems that the threshold is calculated by maxing (Sen+Spe). However, here, it is clearely possible to find a threshold that have a higher Sen+Spe value.

Is the error coming from my code ? (doing  `coords(roc(data$Illness,data$the_predictor, levels=c("Healthy","Sick")), "best", ret = "threshold") %>% unlist()`  just gives the same threshold. Is it coming from the pROC function ?

Help me, I am so lost here.

## Edit : code to copy/paste

```
data=structure(list(Predictor = c(-30.0265168079189, 1.15099363860717, 
                             -11.9804372907826, -5.77111036023964, -2.12543529096544, 3.92087977078597, 
                             5.34247848261018, 4.22335287554391, -23.6137844687066, -19.9373894314097, 
                             -7.66163269551192, 9.13278170787256, -1.36786740246491, -2.72758047450363, 
                             -12.1955983263269, 4.12642888543807, 0.163977606901045, 1.46547604262282, 
                             -1.8412138361035, -6.14477150770652, -3.17570617995096, -30.064951386853, 
                             10.9975933111011, 4.69525214654113, 7.17071677098559, -42.7958812479347, 
                             -22.0530194817619, 5.22959301386168, -5.37225791749525, -8.41992810521969, 
                             0.214693153960777, -10.2699595330821, 7.5188942409622, -8.35948733431006, 
                             -28.3236974772852, -0.334108822977305, 10.3570377885479, -6.21627576016198, 
                             -1.34577632302221, -0.704958574099198, -8.21298595801565, -0.673991917300366, 
                             10.1477239063002, -13.3154432636137, -24.7929589691277, -13.7662638672144, 
                             -11.8388358393301, 1.2811315099285, -16.6351572937165, -11.2898600124526, 
                             -22.8066837752388, 3.56811422380944, -23.3577893771017, -14.1165843206214, 
                             -3.60022726353809, -3.11503373374385, -12.2597492695888, 7.31226134848711, 
                             -11.5833482372835, -16.7535225022961, -8.56422928031759, -47.9699360179454, 
                             -19.7539978196463, -26.3666055391003, -17.2614678085344, 13.2702046763866, 
                             -13.2264594680634, 15.7449331695833, -5.50032293388125, 2.81599579215209, 
                             1.92271901789842, -1.99266757116988, -27.2703581251132, 0.476318001224534, 
                             -6.65722119385071, 2.35294755630814, 13.2977149882188, -15.6037631636617, 
                             1.38135215321582, -9.71125135113497, -4.11971899794967, 5.21192589771364, 
                             5.63060382748609, 3.93730115204109, 12.9318052438389, 6.16873004521188, 
                             0.987650782375663, -11.352515305607, 13.4704068306721, -8.43764175284198, 
                             18.5651453322091, 2.45966987595847, -42.9176544778171, -3.89773417236148, 
                             -28.3070154341685, -13.6189396001791, -8.10091523989799, 2.45341660282897, 
                             3.57427638074422, 16.1254084424853, -13.234491473745, -37.5823778107753, 
                             3.89815090155948, 11.4130217096843, -26.9867338207, -21.9465772218131, 
                             7.34257329115229, -11.3782968157392, -34.7142009728594, -49.8201162965836, 
                             9.29909876231373, -10.0850944178935, 11.6016303844531, 5.23411199811675, 
                             11.7946167683302, 3.28158141564784, 2.03385869625709, -1.89888171264814, 
                             -23.3807367058501, -4.08156864378285, 9.00363191604415, 12.8526886439116, 
                             -13.0772932176236, -8.00976153286771, 8.65199795385856, 15.0607427725054, 
                             14.1375633988393, -8.66285501996315, 10.6594655613105, -17.5706905139599, 
                             6.12042615000835, -3.31329113354379, -3.99151135257908, 8.04726385642244, 
                             -0.56725238509163, -9.36165609862254, -4.62609609004956, -54.3425894866824, 
                             -31.5916887347727, -22.8418309700193, -5.8349028529916, -24.2643112312585, 
                             10.0928208337933, -10.663258246763, 0.154714176468552, 1.94161020180308, 
                             1.23173520914207, -11.5359195732191, 10.4662441932512, -1.15329871483222, 
                             2.48304873375732, 11.1247749589697, 13.600816862598, 5.4048677111595, 
                             7.75142783090626, 12.407508070537, 14.2936521098022, 8.57492908453424, 
                             7.78937753060301, 15.5758817729099, 12.9689634444848, 19.7716027797074, 
                             17.3722434464835, 25.8398368056633, 22.9286256713902, 12.4332591080305, 
                             20.1646775468313, 13.6359691315215, 22.4075156394212, 2.52052660698105, 
                             -16.1294988287829, 24.2580803169934, 6.53302505803349, 28.0007397454365, 
                             12.5997533567436, 19.8231609146357, 20.4758235394322, -3.14132866132124, 
                             15.3652243575294, 5.51333807966991, 12.6701530511479, 7.76875005452657, 
                             9.50414582122118, 7.18440942260985, 17.0577133339618, 1.75973853154878, 
                             19.3991204516457, 17.2086372124398, 11.4946377474413, 18.1208643720225, 
                             13.4371964205874, -1.41932411310972, -0.217642491330989, 0.559828427316018, 
                             14.9513204550895, 8.40789113945641, 7.32690822343274, -10.6306122848244, 
                             8.78982973978855, 19.9236377854904, -16.146128022031, -4.91319750465569, 
                             1.94096133981224, 19.1978399847426, 5.68816798940584, 16.0286843888299, 
                             10.8532049397931, 14.9332042247407, 7.89131242660244, 4.84817793483408, 
                             -23.5709741092812, -5.0750006627721, 9.82990315423877, 13.445883799078, 
                             -16.6078061062201, 8.09109746282265, 4.03027064373712, 7.04329554573276, 
                             -21.7969169325793, 5.17566711827446, 17.7920853961723, 19.5637542942757, 
                             -2.64115652660286, 15.8666090101656, 19.8301694557142, 6.12840423007928, 
                             10.6956110325132, 20.6264711334891, 13.7039419874073, -5.48902063664391, 
                             -13.5307133212758, -3.57547635643989, 8.28126733549754, -28.1686872403507, 
                             21.1407803859056, -1.65377737760872, 0.831092132680901, 16.9496509311116, 
                             -9.18907250852743, 14.8757097896787, 12.2295286749314), Illness = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                           2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                           1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                                                           1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                           2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                           1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                           1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                           1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                                                           1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                           1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                           2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                           1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                           1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                           1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                           1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                           1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
                             ), levels = c("Healthy", "Sick"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                           -241L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

list.predictors=list("Predictor")

summary(data)
map(list.predictors, .f=~{ 
  threshold=coords(roc(data$Illness,data[[.x]], levels=c("Healthy","Sick")), "best", ret = "threshold") %>% unlist()
  c2=data
  c2$NM=ifelse(data[[.x]]>=threshold,"1","0")
  TP=c2 %>% filter(NM!="0" & Illness=="Sick") %>% nrow()
  TN= c2 %>% filter(NM=="0" & Illness=="Healthy") %>% nrow()
  FP=c2 %>% filter(NM!="0" & Illness=="Healthy") %>% nrow()
  FN= c2 %>% filter(NM=="0" & Illness=="Sick") %>% nrow()
  tribble(~"name",~"threshold",~"Sen",~"Spe",~"PPV",~"PNV",
          .x,threshold, TP/(TP+FN), TN/(TN+FP), TP/(TP+FP), TN/(TN+FN)
  ) %>%
    mutate(across((Sen:PNV),~round(.x,2)),
           threshold=round(threshold,3)) %>% return() 
}) %>% bind_rows()
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, specifically I can't load the data, it has missing brakcets and some <> that break it. Make sure to use the `dump` function.

Comment: I edited the reprex using answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533332/cannot-use-dput-for-data-table-in-r)

Comment: And how does this data fit in any of the code you've provided? I don't see any of the code you provided that I can run with it.

Comment: I edited my code. Sorry, I forgot some things during translation/ simplification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe pROC gives the correct optimal threshold. The problem lies in your code which calculates the parameters incorrectly.

Notice the following output line when running the code:

```
Setting direction: controls > cases
```

This indicates that `Predictor` takes lower values in `Sick` cases. As a consequence, you are thresholding the data incorrectly. If you don't know the direction your predictor goes a priori, you should replace:

```
c2$NM=ifelse(data[[.x]]>=threshold,"1","0")
```

with:

```
c2$NM=ifelse(data[[.x]]<threshold,"1","0")
```

which produces the correct output:

```
Setting direction: controls > cases
# A tibble: 1 × 6
  name      threshold   Sen   Spe   PPV   PNV
  <chr>         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Predictor      1.33  0.82  0.59  0.31  0.94
```

In addition you should be able to get the results you want much more easily and without the need to compute the performance values yourself with a pipeline like this:

```
map(list.predictors, .f = ~{ 
  roc(data$Illness, data[[.x]], levels = c("Healthy","Sick")) %>% 
  coords("best", ret = c("threshold", "sensitivity", "specificity", "ppv", "npv")) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(name = .x, .before = "threshold",
         across((sensitivity:npv), ~round(.x, 2)),
         threshold = round(threshold, 3))
}) %>% 
bind_rows()
```

This pipeline produces the same output as yours, using the performance values computed by the coords function.